# R1C1 Notation Macro - Search only for numeric values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having some trouble with my first VBA macro. I'm trying to get my G column to display 1, 2, etc, when a numerical value is found in an adjacent column. It's working for the most part, but it's also counting non-numerical values. The issue is that there can be a max of 9 columns with data; however, there are times when the columns with numbers are not in the spreadsheet, which ends up counting data for whatever 9th column is there...Whether it should be counted or not.

Here's what it currently looks like:
[image]

```
Columns("G:G").Select
TempString = "IF(RC[1]>0,""1,"","""")&IF(RC[2]>0,""2,"","""")&IF(RC[3]>0,""3,"","""")&IF(RC[4]>0,""4,"","""")&IF(RC[5]>0,""5,"","""")&IF(RC[6]>0,""6,"","""")&IF(RC[7]>0,""7,"","""")&IF(RC[8]>0,""8,"","""")&IF(RC[9]>0,""9,"","""")"
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(" + TempString + ") > 0, LEFT( " + TempString + ", LEN( " + TempString + " ) - 1 ), " + TempString + " )"
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("G:G").Formula = Columns("G:G").Value
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Revised Data"
```

I tried to use LIKE, to only look at columns with Grade in the header, but it threw an app error:

```
IF(RC[9]>0 AND R[-1]C[40] LIKE *Grade* THEN ""9,"","""")"
```

Comment: Can you add some more data? I can’t understand from the sample image why count column has 6 and 9. Also are you going to run this multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st macro it is ok, anyway, there are ways to improve your code later.

Anyway, IF(RC[1]>0) will be true in any case when the cell contains any text that is not a negative number or exactly 0 value. You should check if the cell contains a numeric value (ISNUMBER() and ...>0)

Plus one: why you added column 9 to check, it seems to be the "Completed" column. But it won't matter once the function will be fixed.